# How to change the key name in nested json before respone in java

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

While getting the output from an api response it is showing `ArrayList` as a key, but I want to customize it according to my preference.

Actual json:

```
{
    "ArrayList": [
        {
            "id": 507,
            "version": 1,
            "invoiceNumber": "INV16",
            "deleted": false
        }
}
```

I need it like this:

```
{
    "invoice": [
         {
             "id": 507,
             "version": 1,
             "invoiceNumber": "INV16",
             "deleted": false
         }
}
```

Comment: if you have access to the server, change it on the server

Comment: while returning response object i am using List<MyClassDto>, i already try with @JsonRootName("invoices")
and  @JsonProperty("invoice")

Comment: better to add server-side code also for this response, if you have.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant solution, but a json is just a String, you can replace `ArrayList` with `invoice`